# Search class for specific text and return entry number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a kind of unique need of finding one `div` on all divs with same class name that has a specific copy, and return the entry number:

```
<div class="alertme"></div>
<div class="alertme"></div>
<div class="alertme">This text</div>
<div class="alertme"></div>
```

So it would return 2, being 0 is the first `div`.

Comment: Show what you tried at least.

Comment: Hint: [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) or [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), then [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index)

Comment: What does "specific copy" mean? What are you trying to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that what you want, but to get the index of the div that has the `This text` text you could use `:contains` selector with `.index()` method :

```
$('.alertme:contains("This text")').index();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log($('.alertme:contains("This text")').index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertme"></div>
<div class="alertme"></div>
<div class="alertme">This text</div>
<div class="alertme"></div>
```